# symbol's value as variable is void: command, when using ibuffer-sidebar

Tags: helm, debugging, major-mode, ibuffer

I installed ibuffer-sidebar (https://github.com/jojojames/ibuffer-sidebar) and added the following to my `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```
(use-package "ibuffer-sidebar.el")
(require 'ibuffer-sidebar)
(setq ibuffer-sidebar-use-custom-font t)
(setq ibuffer-sidebar-face `(:family "Helvetica" :height 120))
```

After doing this, all helm commands fail. E.g. `helm-find-files` says `In Find FIles source: helm-find-fules-get-candidates (void-variable command)`. Other helm commands just say `symbol's value as variable is void: command`. I'm a newbie, very excited about emacs.

Comment: I hope someone checks whether this is a duplicate. There are a few very common (different) causes behind that error message, for which there are already some questions here.

Comment: Why are you using `(use-package)` with quotes and appending the .el extension? That's not how you usually `use-package`s.

Comment: @AlexPetrosyan could you tell me how to do it? I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is not how people install packages, typically if you want to use use-package, you want to specify everything inside the macro, and what you might be seeing is the spillover into `helm`, because it's initialised after `ibuffer-sidebar`.

I would suggest you read up the documentation, and as an example of how to use `use-package` here's the version of your `init.el`.

```
(use-package ibuffer-sidebar
  :ensure t
  :config
  (custom-set-variables
    '(ibuffer-sidebar-use-custom-font t)
    '(ibuffer-sidebar-face (:family "Helvetica" :height 120)))
```

This might not fix the error that you're having, but it's definitely the proper way to `use-package`.

As for the error message you're receiving, it's a sign that the macro is not getting a command as a value (in lisp, functions are values too), so my best guess would be that it fails to initialise `ibuffer-sidebar` and tries to run one of its provided commands, but fails.

See if this fixes the issue.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to wrap `(use-package...` with `(...)`.

Comment: @ManuelUberti typo. Good catch.